# How to group items with printf?

Tags: java

Is there a way to group items in printf with a width?
I am trying to group a double with a percentage sign while having a fixed width. Here is my code

```
System.out.printf("%-17.3f%%", interestRate * 100);
```

I am trying to get this: `5.125%`.
But instead I am getting `5.125` **with 10+ spaces before the `%` symbol**.

Is there a way i can get this to print `5.125%` with `printf`?

Comment: Just remove the `-`, it will work.`System.out.printf("%17.3f%%", interestRate * 100);`

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `-`, it will work.

```
System.out.printf("%17.3f%%", interestRate * 100);
```

If you give an negative number than it will create space to the right side of the number.
If you give an positive number than it will create space to the left side of the number.

If you want to have blank space to right side and still you want `%` to come just after number. Than sorry but you need to do little work around. In such case you need to prepare it by yourself with the help of string manipulation.

Comment: @JoeG, Have a look at [java docs for string formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.printf("%-17.3f%%", interestRate * 100+"%");
```

Comment: Can you please add some explanation?